# IF Statement on array if it has one or more truthy value

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Here's a quick question I'd like to ask. I have this array, a simple `[false, false, true, false, true]`. If one (or more) of these values are true, then I'd like to pass the virtual IF statement. If there is none, I'd like to fail the statement.

I don't have any code to show you further.

Hopefully you can help me with this, thank you.
~Q

Comment: What do you mean by "*the virtual IF statement.*"? To check values in an array, you need a loop. Try one.

Comment: Because I thought it isn't necessarily a simple `if (condition) { ... } else { ... }`. I might need a loop or some other statement to access it.

Comment: I guess, `array.includes(true)` would be the most readable option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you're looking for is [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```
[false, false, true, false, true].some(Boolean) // true
[false, false, false, false, false].some(Boolean) // false
[true, true, true, true, true, true].some(Boolean) // true
```

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

You can use the includes() method to determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate

```js
var array1 = [false, false, true, false, true];
 
console.log(array1.includes(true));
    // output will be: true
```

or use the method inside if-statement

```js
if (array1.includes(true))  
    console.log(true);
   else
    console.log(fales);
```